# Android Real Scale Application

Tags: android, scale

I have a nice idea for android application want to make real scale, not like others which are fake i was thinking of how to do it but don't have any idea.
**EDIT:** `want to make real scale` **(what means)** It means for example i wanna calculate how much is the weight of a coin, then i'm putting the coin in the screen and calculates how much is the weight of the coin and if its possible the scale to get the weights to 50 grams
Hope its understood now.

Comment: You might consider explaining what "want to make real scale" means.

Comment: OK doesn't matter that i just don't know a good English grammar.

Comment: It is impossible for us to help you when we do not know what you mean. There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in many languages. I have several listed at http://www.andglobe.com. Perhaps one offers help in a language that is more comfortable for you.

Comment: @Stefan You want to make a weighing scale on the phone.? Honestly, I don't think any of the smartphones out there have an api or provide an api to read pressure on screen (which you could use to calculate weight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is possible, just probably not precise enough. Most touch controllers can report touch pressure and it is available via [MotionEvent.getPressure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28%29) call. So with some luck and tedious calibration you can measure weight of something. It is going to work better with cheaper resistive screen.

Comment: but it will be showed the weight around the correct weight right ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Android SDK that supports measuring the weight of a coin.

Comment: i don't mean exactly of a coin it can be something else like weed... :D

Comment: @Stefan: There is nothing in the Android SDK that supports weighing of anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pressure (0-1). Calibrate it with a quarter or known value (quarter is 2.5g). Then if a quarter gives you a pressure value of 0.2, then you know that to calculate weight, you use the formula (p * 2.5/2), where p is the value read from getPressure().
I don't know if you can scale it...
Good Luck.